# question with bounty migrated: bounty disappeared

Tags: support, bounties, migration

2 days ago I answered a question with a 200 bounty in SO. In a few hours my answer had 2 up votes.
Yesterday, when I opened, SO a banner appeared telling me that this question had been moved to webmasters. I went to check the status of my [anwer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26900/pending-status-for-orders-paid-via-auth-net/26901#26901) and was very surprise to see that the bounty had disappeared.
Also, I really don't understand why it had been moved to webmasters. In the first [FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) it says:

> Please note that if your question is about detailed HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding, it might be a better fit on Stack Overflow. We prefer questions here about problems or issues that affect entire websites.

And the question was clearly not an "entire website" issue, and did involved detailed xml.

So, I'm confused:

1. I've lost the bounty points :-(
2. the reputation points I got for this answer went to my webmaster account, but I don't really care about this account, I'd much prefer to have the points in my SO account
3. why was this question moved to webmasters?

I'll apreciate any explanation about those points, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was the moderator who removed the bounty and migrated the question to ProWebMasters.SE.

The question was flagged by the community as not on-topic for Stack Overflow and upon reviewing the flag I noted that the question was about configuring Magento.

Magento administration and configuration questions are not on-topic on Stack Overflow and are more suited for the ProWebMasters.SE site.

Comment: Magento questions are being migrated to *Webmasters* now? I'm not sure that's a good idea - I think most of them should be closed as long as there's no dedicated Magento site. But if the Webmasters mods are okay with it... *shrug*

Comment: @Pekka'sReputationBordello -  http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/547/magento-admin-and-operations-questions - to be honest I am of the same opinion as you.

Comment: @Kev thanx for answering. I still don't think it was a configuration question (I mean, as I said to Sathya, when you have to create a module and write code, even just some xml, this is not configuring), but whatever, it's your call :-)

Answer (score 3):

Bounties are refunded back to the person who started the bounty. Also, not that you hadn't [won the bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9550398/revisions) - the rep graph shows it was refunded

[image]

So,

> I've lost the bounty points :-(

Yeah, tough luck - but till then you hadn't won it, so *technically* you haven't lost it...

> but I don't really care about this account, I'd much prefer to have the points in my SO account

Shucks, that's too bad

> why was this question moved to webmasters?

I assume there were enough flags on the posts requesting migration which resulted in the migration. Also, reading from the question, it seems more of a setting-up in Magneto thing(which is a better target on [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)) rather than a programming question, which resulted in the move.

Comment: I don't consider creating a module in order to change behaviour a "setting-up thing". And the only flag there was was from the question's author. That's a nice trick: 1. create a bounty 2. get an answer 3. move the question and get by my rep. neat.

Comment: @OSdave not sure how you concluded that the flag on the question was by the OP, considering Mod flags cannot be seen by regular users.

Comment: It was *not* the OP that flagged for the question to be migrated. Additionally, I don't see this as a way to game the system since it .. you know .. requires a moderator to take the action for you :)